# How does one visualize the self-organizing map of $n$-dimensional data

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, dimensionality-reduction, self-organizing-maps

I have a data set consisting from $7$-dimensional data points. I want to produce a self-organizing map for this data to see how my data is clustered.

I have been reading some [tutorials](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html) from the internet about SOM and I usually see this classical example of training the SOM to learn colours (the image is cited from http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html):

[image]

I'm a bit confused because I don't know how to produce an image similar to the example above when I have $7$-dimensional data. How is SOM usually visualized with $n$-dimensional data? What should I do specifically?

My question is a bit similar to this question: [Self Organizing Maps: How is the location computed and updated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/206524/18528)

Thank you for any clarifications!

P.S. I'm using Matlab in my analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have done to see how the map fits the data

Wickham, H.; Cook, D. & Hofmann, H. (2015), 'Visualizing statistical models: Removing the blindfold.', Statistical Analysis and Data Mining 8 (4), 203-225 [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sam.11271/abstract;jsessionid=DBDA77487F0A4D51EEA66CFD53D3E9E5.f04t01)

And there are videos at: [ggobi book](http://www.ggobi.org/book/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your contributions here, @DiCook. Be aware that you now have two accounts [new](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/114348/di-cook), [original](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/55365/dianne-cook). Please merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]).

Answer (score 2):

One method I have had success with is to produce a 2D [Sammon Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sammon_mapping) of the trained SOM node vectors. The positions of the nodes on the Sammon Map can then be projected onto a two-dimensional colour space. The distance between the nodes on the Sammon Map is approximately proportional to the distance between the nodes in the original $n$-dimensional data space. Nodes with similar $n$-D vectors will thus be assigned similar colours.